# How to return a widget if I need to go to a new screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

Why do this code in not properly set up? I get the error: This function has a return type of 'Widget', but doesn't end with a return statement.

Obviously, it doesn like the use of Navigator stuff in future builder. How to make it properly?

```
MaterialApp(
    home: const Splash1(),
);

class Splash1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: checkIsSeen(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (snapshot.data == true) {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeView()),
                );
              } else {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const IntroScreen()),
                );
              }
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Icon(
                  Icons.error_outline,
                  size: 60,
              );
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
        }),
    );
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you simple use `return HomeView();` and `return IntroScreen();`, why do you need the `Navigator` here?

Comment: @PeterKoltai probably that's it. There is some unclear stuff - when not using `Navigator.pushReplacement` will not there be memory leak because we will return another `Scaffold` from an already shown one?

Comment: I don think so. The `Scaffold` remains the same, only the `body` is rebuilt and it means it is replaced in the widget tree with `HomeView`, `IntroScreen`, `Icon` or `CircularProgressIndicator`.

Comment: `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` are the proper ways to handle async widgets, check [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/async). As far as I know It is not recommended to use different async methods in `build`.

Comment: @PeterKoltai not necessarily the Scaffold remains the same. These `HomeView` and `IntroScreen` are full-featured widgets (screens) that have their own scaffold .

Comment: I will post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `HomeView` and `IntroScreen` both contain a `Scaffold`, you can reorganise your code like this, without using `Navigator` in the `build` method:

```
class Splash1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash1({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: checkIsSeen(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return snapshot.data ? const HomeView() : const IntroScreen();
          } else {
            return Scaffold(
                body: snapshot.hasError
                    ? const Icon(
                        Icons.error_outline,
                        size: 60,
                      )
                    : const CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: it's the way I actually resolve it, but probably it's worth to open new thread about returning different scaffolds in the same build() method

Comment: Good to hear that it works for you. IMO there is nothing bad with returning different  `Scaffold` widgets from a build method. If you need the same `Scaffold` you can change `HomeView` and `IntroScreen` to build only the body.

Answer (score 1):

There is a **statement** about your issue (Obviously, it does not like the use of `Navigator` stuff in the future builder.). `Future.builder` shouldn't include logic beyond building widgets (e.g. **don't call** `Navigator.push`).

Instead of FutureBuilder, you can just put the async call in build().

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    check().then((success) {
      if (success) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
      } else {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
      }
    });
```

You can learn more about this issue at this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16218